# Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces

Tags: python

Obtengo el error:

> "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces"

Ya he visto las soluciones que dan, pero lo que sucede es que para solucionarlo el error de identación tengo que regresar una tabulacion a cada linea, y eso es tedioso, ¿Existe alguna forma de regresar una tabulacion a todo un conjunto de lineas?, gracias por su respuesta.
Se muestra parte del codigo
`introducir el código aquí`

```
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import * 

import sqlite3 

class Product:
    db_name="database.db" 
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.wind=window
        self.wind.title("Product Application")

    def validation(self):
        return len(self.name.get() !=0 and len(self.price.get())!=0)

        def add_product(self):
            if self.validation():

                query='INSERT INTO product VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)'
                parameters=(self.name.get(),self.price.get())
                self.run_query(query, parameters)
                self.message['text']='Product {} added Successfully'.format(self.name.get())
                self.name.delete(0,END)
                self.price.delete(0,END)
                print(self.name.get())
                print(self.price.get())
            else:
                self.message['text']='Name and Price are Required'
                print('Name and price is required')
            self.get_products() 

if __name__=='__main__':
    window= Tk()
    application= Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 permite usar tanto tabulaciones como espacios para identar el código , **siempre y cuando no se mezclen en un mismo módulo**. Eso es lo que está pasando en tu caso y por eso la excepción. O se usan espacios o tabulaciones, pero no ambas cosa a la vez.

Sea como sea, deberías evitar las tabulaciones siempre, para empezar no son iguales entre editores, dependen del tabstops que use cada uno, por lo que la visualización del código puede diferir según en el editor o plataforma en la que se visualice.

Por otro lado, es recomendable seguir las convenciones de estilo y usar siempre cuatro espacios por nivel de indentación.

Por norma general, cualquier editor o IDE decente preparado para Python identa por defecto con cuatro espacios, aún así es un error muy común por ejemplo al copiar y pegar código obtenido de la web e insertarlo en un script propio.

Al pegar el código aquí se han perdido las tabulaciones, pero por el error de identación que hay en el código parece que el afectad es el método `add_product`. Dependiendo de tu editor/IDE normalmente hay una opción para mostrar caracteres no imprimibles y espacios, solo tendrías que eliminar las tabulaciones ya sustituirlas por los correspondientes espacios. Muchos IDEs además tiene una opción para corregir la identación y normalizarla.

Sea como sea, tu código corregido sería:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 
import sqlite3 



class Product:
    db_name="database.db" 
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.wind=window
        self.wind.title("Product Application")

    def validation(self):
        return len(self.name.get() !=0 and len(self.price.get())!=0)

    def add_product(self):
        if self.validation():
            query='INSERT INTO product VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)'
            parameters=(self.name.get(),self.price.get())
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text']='Product {} added Successfully'.format(self.name.get())
            self.name.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.price.delete(0, tk.END)
            print(self.name.get())
            print(self.price.get())
        else:
            self.message['text']='Name and Price are Required'
            print('Name and price is required')
        self.get_products() 


if __name__=='__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    application= Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```